# Joined MySQL relationship only outputting one row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables all related to the User.

The three tables in question are: User, Dealers, Collars.

The issue here is that a User can have many collars and my join statements are only outputting one collar even though there's multiple associated.

However, I know it's finding the multiple collars associated with the user_id because if I instead add `GROUP_CONCAT(collars.collar_id)` to my sql statement, it will show the two collar_ids the user has.

It's outputting one collar because the array it's being returned to has keys which each collar output is overriding as there cannot be duplicate array keys.

This is my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT u.*
     , d.*
     , c.*
  FROM users u
  JOIN dealers d
    ON d.id = u.dealer_id_foreign
  JOIN user_collars uc
    ON uc.user_id = u.user_id
  JOIN collars c
    ON c.collar_id = uc.collar_id
 WHERE u.user_id = :id
```

My question is, can I use one SQL statement to return all information I want that this User is related to? Maybe a multidimensional array so all collars can be returned?

Note: I'm using PHP PDO to execute this. that's what the ":id" variable is in the select statement.

EDIT: I'm going to provide a fuller example of my table structure and the array output I'm hoping to achieve with my SELECT statement.

User Table:

```
+---------+-------------------+
| user_id | dealer_id_foreign |
+---------+-------------------+
|    1811 |                55 |
|    1812 |                67 |
+---------+-------------------+
```

Dealers Table

```
+----+--------------------+
| id |    dealer name     |
+----+--------------------+
| 55 | dealer guy         |
| 56 | another dealer guy |
+----+--------------------+
```

Collars Table

```
+-----------+---------------------+
| collar_id |        name         |
+-----------+---------------------+
|        26 | some collar name    |
|        27 | another collar name |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

User_Collars Table (Relationship Table)

```
+-----------+---------+
| collar_id | user_id |
+-----------+---------+
|        26 |    1811 |
|        27 |    1811 |
+-----------+---------+
```

As you can see, the user with the id of '1811' owns two collars. When I'm querying a user by id, in this case 1811, I'd like all relationship info output via the query i.e. the dealer the user is connected to and all the collars they own.

I won't include everything in example array, but this should be example

```
Array (

[user_id] => 1811
[user_name] => 'whatever'
[dealer_name] 'the dealer name',
[collars] => [
  [some_key_1] => [
    [collar_id] => 26
  ],

  [some_key_2] => [
    [collar_id] => 27
  ]
]
)
```

Now I realize I'm asking MySQL to provide formatting, which I know is unreasonable, but what I essentially want is a single record output with the ability to get all the collars.

Comment: you're likely limited by the `dealers` table. If your user only has one row in there then the entire query will be limited to that one row. `INNER JOIN` will only bring in rows that match.  You can use `LEFT JOIN dealers ...` to show all the rows however if that data is unrelated you may need to remove it altogether.

Comment: I think you're right. If I get rid of dealers in the query and change my PDO from Single to FetchAll, it will return two arrays, though both arrays are duplicating the user information. I was hoping to have one array output with the x amount of collars in a 'collars' key. so multidimensional array essentially. If I add the dealer join last, it will return all rows. just not how I want. perhaps I just need to use PHP to format my data, though I suspect theres a better way using mysql to organize my outputted data.

Comment: Yes that's correct because you have select `users.*` so each row is self contained and will have all that information.  If you want just the collars information you could do `SELECT collars.* FROM user_collars uc JOIN users ON uc.users_id = users.user_id WHERE users.user_id=:id`

Comment: Thanks, I'll just need to do that. I was hoping I could query all user information and their belongings. Ill just reformat my return with PHP

Comment: And if you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: thanks everyone. I'll edit my answer soon and show a fuller example with the array output i'm hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your query as it stands, it correctly returns two rows of data as you can see in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b0f33b0a2b7111e426449eb52ba8264c):

```
user_id     dealer_id_foreign   id  dealer name     collar_id   name
1811        5              5    55  dealer guy      26          some collar name
1811        55                  55  dealer guy      27          another collar name
```

If you want to get all the information in one row, then you need to group the collar values by `user_id`:

```
SELECT u.user_id
     , d.id AS dealer_id
     , d.`dealer name`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(c.collar_id) AS collar_ids
     , GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) AS collar_names
  FROM users u
  JOIN dealers d
    ON d.id = u.dealer_id_foreign
  JOIN user_collars uc
    ON uc.user_id = u.user_id
  JOIN collars c
    ON c.collar_id = uc.collar_id
 WHERE u.user_id = 1811
 GROUP BY u.user_id, d.id
```

This will give you comma separated lists of collar id and name values (for each user/dealer combination) in your result:

```
user_id     dealer_id   dealer name     collar_ids  collar_names
1811        55          dealer guy      26,27       some collar name,another collar name
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=be5bc76024cb836c85285ca7e6566807)

In your application framework you can then combine the collar id and name values, for example in PHP you might do something like:

```
$collars = array_combine(explode(',', $row['collar_ids']), explode(',', $row['collar_names']));
```

which would give you an output like:

```
Array ( 
    [26] => some collar name
    [27] => another collar name 
)
```

Or if you just want the collar id's

```
$collars = explode(',', $row['collar_ids']);
```

which would give you an output like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 26
    [1] => 27
)
```